# Getting a "not a single-group group function" error. All non-aggregate columns have been listed in the group by

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, ora-00937

```html
SELECT    STATUS, 
          AVG(COUNT(CRIME_ID)) "Avg # of Crimes per Status"
FROM      CRIMES
GROUP BY  STATUS;
```

When I try to run this I get the "not a single-group group by function". As you can see I have included the non-aggregated column in the group by list. When it is removed from the SELECT list it runs, but I need to run it with it. What is the problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Oracle doesn't allow for nesting two aggregate functions in this way when also selecting the group.  Subquery the count query and then take the average:

```sql
SELECT AVG(cnt)
FROM
(
    SELECT STATUS, COUNT(CRIME_ID) AS cnt
    FROM CRIMES
    GROUP BY STATUS
) t;
```

Note that you could try:

```
SELECT AVG(COUNT(CRIME_ID)) OVER () AS avg
FROM CRIMES
GROUP BY STATUS
ORDER BY STATUS
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Here we are using `AVG()` as an analytic function over all groups in the result set.  Then, we limit the output to just one row.

Comment: Thank you, that's what it was. We haven't even learned subqueries yet so I would have not thought to do this. We learned that you can nest aggregate functions no more than two deep, has this changed?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking here...check the second half of my answer for what you were trying to do.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, why don't you delete this answer or at least remove the false statement?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle actually does allow for nesting two aggregate functions from its earlier versions, but doing so means that there are two aggregations, the first one with a GROUP BY clause but the one following it - without.
This means we cannot select the columns in the GROUP BY -
and that is the source of the error.

By removing the `STATUS` column from the `SELECT` clause, we get a valid query:

```
SELECT    AVG(COUNT(CRIME_ID)) "Avg # of Crimes per Status"
FROM      CRIMES
GROUP BY  STATUS;
```

| Avg # of Crimes per Status |
| --- |
| 3.33333333333333333333333333333333333333 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d5a9b87b62f9c9f11c58c8488cf33f56)

> "**You can nest aggregate functions**. For example, the following example
> calculates the average of the maximum salaries of all the departments
> in the scott schema:
>
> `SELECT AVG(MAX(salary)) FROM employees GROUP BY department_id;`
>
> AVG(MAX(SALARY))
> `----------------
> 10925
>
> This calculation evaluates the inner aggregate (MAX(sal)) for each
> group defined by the GROUP BY clause (deptno), and aggregates the
> results again."

[Oracle9i SQL Reference Release 1 (9.0.1)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A91034_01/DOC/server.901/a90125/functions2.htm#80856)